# SQL Server COUNT Issue - not showing zero counts

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, count

I am trying to run what I thought would be a simple `COUNT` query, albeit, I'm not very well-versed in `COUNT`.

I am running:

```
SELECT SourceID, COUNT(*) as SourceCount
FROM dbo.Capture
WHERE SourceID in (37, 38, 130, 131, 132, 133)
GROUP BY SourceID
```

The results of this query only show rows where `SourceID` has a COUNT greater than zero records.  How can I get the results to show ALL those SourceID's including ones with no count, next to which I would want to see a zero or NULL in the `SourceCount` column, doesn't matter which.

Thanks.

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand your question, can you please post a sample data and expected results (as formatted text).

Comment: Do you want to get all values even if their recurrence equals zero?

Comment: Are you saying that for example 37 and 38 don't exist in the table but you want to see them anyway? You need to outer join to a table that lists all of the possible ID's. The database doesn't know that 37 doesn't exist so you need a table listing them all. Where does that IN list come from? manually entered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
SELECT SourceID, COUNT(*) AS SourceCount FROM dbo.Capture
WHERE SourceID IN (37, 38, 130, 131, 132, 133)
GROUP BY SourceID
UNION
SELECT *,0 FROM dbo.Split('137, 38, 130, 131, 132, 133',',')
WHERE item NOT IN (SELECT SourceID FROM dbo.Capture WHERE SourceID IN (37, 38, 130, 131, 132, 133))
```

And here is the source code for `dbo.Split` function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Split] (@InputString VARCHAR(8000),@Delimiter VARCHAR(50))
RETURNS @Items TABLE (Item VARCHAR(8000))
AS
BEGIN
      IF @Delimiter = ' '
      BEGIN
            SET @Delimiter = ','
            SET @InputString = REPLACE(@InputString, ' ', @Delimiter)
      END

      IF (@Delimiter IS NULL OR @Delimiter = '')
            SET @Delimiter = ','

      DECLARE @Item           VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @ItemList       VARCHAR(8000)
      DECLARE @DelimIndex     INT

      SET @ItemList = @InputString
      SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      WHILE (@DelimIndex != 0)
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, 0, @DelimIndex)
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)

            SET @ItemList = SUBSTRING(@ItemList, @DelimIndex+1, LEN(@ItemList)-@DelimIndex)
            SET @DelimIndex = CHARINDEX(@Delimiter, @ItemList, 0)
      END -- End WHILE

      IF @Item IS NOT NULL -- At least one delimiter was encountered in @InputString
      BEGIN
            SET @Item = @ItemList
            INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@Item)
      END

      -- No delimiters were encountered in @InputString, so just return @InputString
      ELSE INSERT INTO @Items VALUES (@InputString)

      RETURN

END -- End Function
```

Comment: Later version of SQL now have a built in split function

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT val.id, COUNT(*) as SourceCount
FROM (values (37), (38), (130), (131), (132), (133)) val(id)
LEFT JOIN dbo.Capture
  on SourceID = val.id
GROUP BY val.id
```

Answer (score 0):

try subquery

```
SELECT m.SourceID, (
        SELECT COALESCE((COUNT(*), 0) FROM dbo.Capture WHERE SourceID = m.SourceID) AS SourceCount
        FROM dbo.Capture m
        WHERE SourceID IN (37, 38, 130, 131, 132, 133)
        GROUP BY SourceID
        )
```

Comment: Given query has error. "Incorrect syntax near ','."